# Different link in wordpress menu if i log in and not

Tags: wordpress

Today i migrated my site from my dev hosting (goDaddy) to customer's hosting (unknown bad service, but customer want it).
1) Copied all files
2) Copied DB (corrected domains like in here)

It's result http://alpenarms.at

Problem: CONTACT link had my old dev link. I corrected it with WP-admin. And I can see changes if i log in. But i ope incognito, another browser, and have old link on CONTACT menu. it's now my browser cache 100%. i have wordpress cache plugins as i know.

Who can tell me what is it? I have not any contacts with hosting customer support. I can add all information that you need to help me. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wordpress CLI to change links in database:

## Search and replace but skip one column

```
$ wp search-replace 'http://example.test' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/#examples

Or use search replace script: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Changing links search also for link's like this: `http:\/\/example.pl\/page`

If links are changed correctly - clear page cache if you have any cache plugin.